# How to organize bash files in such way that I can use folders for better structure to be used in "import... path" dependencies?

Tags: linux, bash

My bash scripts started to grow and I need to put some folder structure to them. Till now I had everything in one single folder, so referencing a file into another file has been super easy and super useful.
Now I started to migrate a folder structure like:

1. deploy
2. azure
3. operation
4. certificates
   and so on...

The problem is the deploy scrips uses azure, azure user operations and you can see now the problems...

Please share any idea, or sample that could solve all the problems with the dependencies.

Thanks in advance to any suggestion!

**EDIT:**

To be clear the problem is that the script cannot be execute from their folder. I need to go at the root an to execute everything in order to satisfy the import. So, executing at the root is an option, but every execution takes a lot of typing ....
The other option is to have all the script in a single folder. But that's the problem that I to avoid, since the number has been growing and I need some categorization and grouping of the queries.

Comment: Can you describe what problems you see?

Comment: Because I import files, the import path is completely broken. The only option that I see is to run any script from the root, but that's quite ugly, since I end up having a lot of bash/operation/run/script_x.sh